# SQL Server 2008 R2 logging query execution times incorrect

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

EDIT: I added all of the code for the logon trigger.

Why am I getting some incorrect results when trying to retrieve the total time it takes for a query to run? This is within the context of a logon trigger on SQL Server 2008 R2.

For testing purposes, I want to get the a rough estimate of the total time it takes for a logon trigger to run. Here is a small sample of the results:

```
LogonId  AppId  TotalLogonTime (in MS)
 101      1        0
 253      2        3
 289      2        3
 985      1       -3
 325      1        0
```

How can the total time evaluate to be negative? Out of the 2.3 million executions so far, there have been 25 that resulted in a time of -3 ms. Here is the code:

```
CREATE trigger [trgAudit]
on all server
with execute as 'TriggerLogonUser'
for logon
as
begin
    set nocount on
    set transaction isolation level read committed

declare
     @LoginTime datetime
    ,@IsWindowsUser bit
    ,@TotalLogonTimeMS int
    ,@ClientNetAddress varchar(48)
    ,@MacAddress nchar(12)
    ,@CurrentUserId int -- UserNames
    ,@ApplicationId int
    ,@HonId int --HostName
    ,@LogonId int --Logon
    ,@MacId int -- MacAddress
    ,@CnaId int -- ClientNetAddress

begin try
    /*
    *** Get the login time, user type, mac address, and client net address  
    */
 select
      @LoginTime = getdate(),
      @IsWindowsUser = case
                          when len(nt_domain) = 0
                             then 0
                          else 1
                       end,
      @MacAddress = p.net_address,
      @ClientNetAddress = convert(varchar(48),connectionproperty('client_net_address'))
 from sys.sysprocesses p
 where 
      p.spid = @@spid

 /*
 *** Client Net Address
 */          
      select top 1
           @CnaId = CnaId
      from master.sysmaintenance.ClientNetAddress with(index(IX_CnaAddress))
      where @ClientNetAddress = CnaAddress

      --if the ip does not exist, insert it.
      if @CnaId is null
           begin
                insert master.sysmaintenance.ClientNetAddress(CnaAddress)
                     values (@ClientNetAddress)
                select @CnaId = @@identity
           end

 /*
 *** Applications
 */     
      select top 1
           @ApplicationId = AppId
      from master.sysmaintenance.Applications with(index(IX_AppName))
      where app_name() = AppName

      if @ApplicationId is null
           begin
                insert master.sysmaintenance.Applications (AppName)
                     values (app_name())
                select @ApplicationId = @@identity
           end

 /*
 *** HostName
 */     
      select top 1
           @HonId = HonId
      from master.sysmaintenance.HostName with(index(IX_HonName))
      where HonName = host_name()

      if @HonId is null
           begin
                insert master.sysmaintenance.HostName
                     values (host_name())

                select @HonId = @@identity
           end

 /*
 *** UserNames
 */     
      select top 1
           @CurrentUserId = UsnId
      from master.sysmaintenance.Usernames with(index(IX_UsnName))
      where UsnName = original_login()

      if @CurrentUserId is null
           begin
                insert master.sysmaintenance.Usernames
                     values (original_login())

                select @CurrentUserId = @@identity
           end

 /*
 *** MacAddress
 */     
      select top 1
           @MacId = MacId
      from master.sysmaintenance.MacAddress with(index(IX_MacAddress))
      where MacAddress = @MacAddress

      -- same logic is continued as in the applications
      if @MacId is null
           begin
                insert master.sysmaintenance.MacAddress (MacAddress)
                     values (@MacAddress)

                select @MacId = @@identity
           end

 /*
 *** Get the total logon time
 */     
 select @TotalLogonTimeMS = datediff(ms,@LoginTime, getdate())

  -- insert ids of the data gathered on the logon event into the logon table.


           insert master.sysmaintenance.Logon ( LogAppId,
                                                LogHonId,
                                                IsWindowsLogon,
                                                CurrentLogonId,
                                                LogonDatetime,
                                                LogCnaId,
                                                LogMacId,
                                                LogonTimeMS )
                values ( @ApplicationId,
                         @HonId,
                         @IsWindowsUser,
                         @CurrentUserId,
                         @LoginTime,
                         @CnaId,
                         @MacId,
                         @TotalLogonTimeMS
                       )
end try

begin catch
    print cast(error_number()    as nvarchar(11))
    print cast(error_severity()  as nvarchar(11))
    print cast(error_state()     as nvarchar(11))
    print cast(error_procedure() as nvarchar(126))
    print cast(error_line()      as nvarchar(11))
    print cast(error_message()   as nvarchar(2048))
end catch
end
```

Here is the DDL to the Logon Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [sysmaintenance].[Logon](
    [LogonId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LogAppId] [int] NULL,
    [LogHonId] [int] NULL,
    [LogMacId] [int] NULL,
    [LogCnaId] [int] NULL,
    [IsWindowsLogon] [bit] NULL,
    [CurrentLogonId] [int] NULL,
    [LogonDatetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [LogonTimeMS] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [PK_Logon] ON [sysmaintenance].[Logon] 
(
    [LogonId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: Try to split this line: `select @TotalLogonTimeMS = datediff(ms,@LoginTime, getdate())` First: `select @LoginTime_FINISH = getdate())` Second: `select @TotalLogonTimeMS = datediff(ms,@LoginTime, @LoginTime_FINISH)`

Comment: `TotalLogonTime` of `2` is impossible as `datetime` always ends in `0`,`3`, or `7`

Comment: You are correct, the 3rd record is supposed to be a 3. Copy-pasta error. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GETDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188383.aspx):

> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset. **This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running.**

Now, bearing in mind that computer clocks drift, I'd imagine that if the computer's time was corrected (either manually or automatically), the time reported by two successive calls to `GETDATE()` (that aren't part of a single query) could go backwards. All of the datetime methods ultimately rely on the computer's clock.

It's a shame you're not logging one of these `GETDATE()` results alongside the timing, so you could see if they all occurred at the same "time".

Comment: This issue is becoming more and more common. So far, there have been 5+ million connections since yesterday, and 78 resulted in a logon time of -3ms. 5.4 million were 0ms. Only about 50 connections were 16ms or lower. It doesn't seem likely that the computers time was corrected that causes this issue.

By the way, the @LoginTime is being logged with the timing. I didn't post the entire code of the trigger because it was not relevant. I am using repetitive logic to capture the application name, ip address, username, etc.

Comment: @GGpsm - "I didn't post the entire code of the trigger because it was not relevant" - it's possible that something you've deemed irrelevant is actually relevant. I posted my answer based on all of the information we have available. **If** you've correctly reduced the whole trigger down to just the relevant portions, then the above is the only vector I'm aware of that can cause multiple `GETDATE()` calls to return timestamps that run backwards.

Comment: @GGpsm - I've not validated [this persons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102064/clock-drift-on-windows) situation, but they claimed significant clock drift over a matter of minutes. And all *we're* looking for is a correction of ~7ms to happen.

Comment: I will edit the original post with the entire trigger without omitting any code.

Comment: After looking at this for quite some time now, I noticed that the "negative time" happens the most during peak times. This is the best explanation that I've come across, so I am going to mark this as the answer.